# Error: could not unlock signer account

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract, web3-providers

> Error: could not unlock signer account

Using web wallet to manage accounts in browser. But getting the above error when calling a function of a smart contract. This happen after updating the web provider with a different `keystore`.

Updating the Web3 Provider:

```
// Hack to provide backwards compatibility for Truffle, which uses web3js 0.20.x
Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = 
    Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;

var web3Provider = new HookedWeb3Provider({
   host: "https://mainnet.infura.io/[TOKEN]",
  transaction_signer: keystore
});

this.web3.setProvider(web3Provider); //Will overide MetaMask Injected Provider!
```

Calling some method:

```
  await deployedDApp.someFunction(
    param1, param2, param3, 0
    , { from: web_wallet_account, gas: 1000000 }
  );
```

Note: I do not want to unlock the account on the node. I just want to use a keystore that is generated in the web using eth-lightwallet. However, web3._provider.transaction_signer is already set well and have the address of my web wallet account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Provider is needed to set at contract-level (for each contract). 
At initialization time, and every time, you update the Web3 provider. You need to update it for all contracts that you are using:

So, in case of updating the web provider as following example:

```
var web3Provider = new HookedWeb3Provider({
  host: "https://mainnet.infura.io/[Token]",
  transaction_signer: keystore
});

this.web3.setProvider(web3Provider);
```

This then has to be repeated for every contract.

```
contractAbstraction.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```